# TortoiseSVN 1.7 client could not open 1.6-server

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, tortoisesvn

My TortoiseSVN version is `1.7.11.23600`,

and my Server is: `Powered by Subversion version 1.6.3 (r38063).`

when i try to open repo-browser, it will say:

```
unable to connect to a repository at URL xxx,
Access to xxx forbidden.
```

The same problem occurs in the use idea-ide's plugin ,but not happend when i useie, cmd-line or eclipse's plugin.
what can i do ? rollback to 1.6?

Comment: The error explains what's the case here: **Access to xxx forbidden.** Check your access permissions and credentials.

Comment: @bahrep thanks for your comment,i know access is forbidden,but i dont know why i was blocked. 
the tortoiseSVN not show the password input dialog.


**If the repository that you are trying to access is password protected, an authentication Dialog will show up.**

Comment: clear auth cache: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-saved-data

Comment: @bahrep oh,yes, i had clean this out before ask this question. but no working.

Comment: Try from CLI, with username-password defined in command options - and always troubleshoot SVN without any GUI

Comment: @LazyBadger thanks lazy,as my question, there is no problem by using cli, ie, eclipse-subclipse. 

last night, i found it, eclipse-subclipse's svnkit 1.3 is ok, but svnkit 1.7 die. and 1.3's target is svn 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, may be this question is too simple ,nobody want to answer it.
but it is a question.

svnkit 1.3 work well, 1.7 will crash down.
rollback to 1.3.